# GLFW huge fps drop when increasing resolution

Tags: opengl, glfw

I noticed today that based on the window size, even a simple render loop that just clears the colors and swap buffers can have widely varying performance.

For example, consider the following render loop

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}
```

If I run this with window resolution 800x600 I get about 1400fps on my laptop that has a GTX880M GPU. The same loop with 2560x1440 resolution runs at about 150fps!. Is this normal? I understand that the resolution can have a huge impact on performance but can it really run 10x slower even when I am not rendering anything and I am simply just clearing the color and swapping buffers?

Comment: Clears [aren't free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer%27s_principle).  You're touching an order of magnitude more pixels (480000 vs 3686400) and it goes an order of magnitude slower (0.7 ms/frame vs 6.6 ms/frame), implying you're working with ~2.2-2.7 GiB/s of memory bandwidth, suggesting you're hitting the Intel GPU in that laptop and not the Nvidia one ([~160 GiB/s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_800M_series)).

Comment: @genpfault I am pretty sure I am running the program on Nvidia GPU and not the integrated one. In Nvidia global settings, I set the option to  High Performance from auto for all apps. Do I need to do something extra? Also, strangely when I run the app, both the integrated GPU and the Nvidia one show close to 100% usage.

Comment: "I get about 1400fps" well, you may get 1400 iterations of that loop per second, but that has nothing to do with what you'll actually see on the screen... You're wasting a huge amount of CPU cycles, burning it, having the fan work like crazy, for really no benefit. That's why you see 100% CPU usage: the busy loop. You should probably use something like `glfwSwapInterval` to enable vsync and not waste CPU cycles. You'll then likely see no decrease in performance — both will have a limited, reasonable FPS number.

Comment: @Bruno Reis That does not seem accurate. First of all, my CPU is not even close to 100% usage, it is at like 20% usage. The GPU however is sitting at 99% usage. And when I time the loop iterations, I indeed jump from 0.7ms (when res is 800x600) to about 7 ms (when res is 2560x1440).

The reason I started trying this  is because my engine itself kinda runs slower than expected and I was wondering if there is some inefficiency in my code or if something is wrong with glfw or from the way I build the projects.

Note: Tried both debug and release builds, got the exact same fps in both cases.

Comment: Since the framebuffer data has to be copied over from the nvidia GPu to the integrated one for output, you will get abour 2.2GByte/s traffic with that resolution and frame rate. However, as the copy engine works asynchronous to the render pipleine, you can do actual render work during that time which is just wasted in your toy example.

Comment: @derhass thank you, now it makes total sense. Since the monitor is connwcted to the integrated GPU (kinda) everything has to flow through that thing huh? But when I am loading and unloading stuff like textures, buffers and all that, the integrated GPU should not show those things down right?

Comment: No it shouldn't. Only the final image will have to be copied.